# jquery getJSON from local url

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

Hi everyone i develop web map using openlayer.

i use geojson, i have this code from :
https://scraperwiki.com/views/openlayers_geojson_example/edit/

this is code :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

// Start position for the map (hardcoded here for simplicity)
var lat=50.90685
var lon=-1.4029
var zoom=12

var map; //complex object of type OpenLayers.Map 

//Initialise the 'map' object
$(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/66016.geojson",
    "callback=?",
    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
        layers: [
            new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Mapnik("Mapnik"),
        ],
        controls: [
          new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
          new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
          new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
          new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()],
        maxResolution: 'auto',
      });

      var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat)
        .transform(
          new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
          map.getProjectionObject()
        );

      map.setCenter(lonLat, zoom);

      var vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON");

      var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();

      var geometry = geojson_format.parseGeometry(data);
      geometry.transform(
          new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
          map.getProjectionObject()
      );

      var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geometry);

      vector_layer.addFeatures([feature]);

      map.addLayer(vector_layer);
    })
});
</script>
```

in :

```
$.getJSON("http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/66016.geojson",
        "callback=?",
```

it works when i call from iis localhost
i try to change like this :

```
$.getJSON("assets/json/66016.geojson",
        "callback=?",
```

but it didnt work, :(

please help me why and how to make this work.

this is the wrong :

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
localhost --- >/assets/json/66016.geojson?callback=jQuery152048599341535009444_1366340277133&_=1366340277237

Comment: "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Comment: What do you see in the console and network tab?

Comment: the problem could be the relative path used. the solution will be is to use url with contextpath of the application, something like `contextPath + '/assets/json/66016.geojson'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, finnaly i get my answer this is the solve :

```
$.getJSON("assets/json/66016.geojson",
        "callback=?",
```

just erase  "callback=?",

```
$.getJSON("/assets/json/66016.geojson",
```

Comment: There is more difference between your two URLs than just the removal of `callback=?`. Your second call begins with '/', while your first does not. Watch out for relative paths. Is your application deployed at the root of the site, or in a sub-folder?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$.getJSON("/assets/json/66016.geojson",
        "callback=?",
```